# Variable as an index? CPLEX

Tags: cplex

I want to find the shortest path using CPLEX in java. To do so, I have a  matrix with all transition costs as follows:

```
M= c(1->1) c(1->2) c(1->3) c(1->4)
   c(2->1) c(2->2) c(2->3) c(2->4)
   c(3->1) c(3->2) c(3->3) c(3->4)
   c(4->1) c(4->2) c(4->3) c(4->4)
```

I've defined a vector (variable) to compute the path. Inside the constraints I make X(0)=1 and X(4)=4 to tell I want to go from position 1 and end up in position 4 as follows:

```
int[][] M = {{0, 2, 3, 40},
             {2, 0, 3, 2},
             {1, 5, 0, 2},
             {2, 4, 5, 0}};

IloCplex cplex = new IloCplex();

// Variable
IloNumVar[] routingVar = new IloNumVar[4];

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  routingVar[i] = cplex.intVar(1, 4);

// Objective
IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();

/* THIS IS WRONG -- Start*/

for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
  objective.addTerm(routingVar[i], M[routingVar[i-1]][routingVar[i]]);

/* THIS IS WRONG -- End*/

cplex.addMinimize(objective);

// Constraints
cplex.addEq(routingVar[0], 1);
cplex.addEq(routingVar[3], 4);

cplex.solve();
```

From what I could find, CPLEX does not allows to use a variable as an index. So, how can i define the cost function? Any suggestions as workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "CPLEX do not allows to use a variable as an index".  This seems unlikely.  Whether you write  ```someCall(foo[42])``` or ```n = 42; someCall(foo[n])```, the someCall method is seeing the single value from the array, not some indexed array expression.  In what way is "THIS IS WRONG" manifested?  What is ```M``` in Java terms?

Comment: @another-dave its quite likely. The key is, that this inner object is a variable and not a constant. It's unevaluated / unknown at this time. And transforming the problem accordingly leads to non-convexity in general

Comment: Shortest path can be computed through a polynomial-size lp. Google for some references. No need for integer-programming. Not only leads your approach to a potentially huge increase in solving time, but formulating this itself like that calls for ugly indicator variables and co. I highly recommend reading about the standard approaches. Yours looks more like constraint-programming than mathematical-opt.

Answer (score 1):

Sascha is right that there are much better suited algorithms than mixed-integer programming to solve a shortest path problem...

But if you really want to use CPLEX, you need to use [indicator constraints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/indicator_constr/02_indicators_defn.html) or big-M formulations.